# In C, how can I ensure that length of an initialized string is less than specified

Tags: c, string, initializer

I have a `struct` where a member is a string with a maximum length of `N`. The definition:

```
typedef struct
{
    const char foo[N];
} bar_t;
```

I expect users of this struct to initialize the `foo` member with a length of no more than `N`:

```
bar_t mybar = { .foo = "12345678" };
```

where `N=8`. Since I can not control all initializations of `bar_t`, I want to rely on the compiler to generate warnings/errors if `bar_t.foo` has length greater than `N`.

The problem is that to account for the terminator character (to be able to use `bar_t.foo` as a normal string), I would need to specify `bar_t.foo` with length `N+1`

Alternatively, I could set the length of `bar_t.foo` to `N` and get the compiler warnings when initialized with a string with length `> N` but I now need to be explicit with the expected string length (i.e. with `strn*()` family of functions with `N` as the max length argument) when using functions that expect a terminator character.

Is there a way to get compiler to be restrictive about the length of initializers AND also be able to treat the field without being explicit about the max string length?

Comment: How about an opposite tactic: always append a null character to the string literal: `.foo = "12345678\0"`?

Answer (score 1):

GCC won't warn about the string initializer longer than the allocated memory, since it is completely legal. But you can provide a compile-time check using macros and static assertions similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 6
typedef struct
{
    const char foo[N];
} bar_t;

#define INIT_FOO(var, initString) \
     _Static_assert(sizeof(initString) < N, "Bad length!"); \
     bar_t var = { .foo = initString };

INIT_FOO(mybar, "Good");
//INIT_FOO(mybar, "Baaaad");

int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", mybar.foo);
    return 0;
}
```

See it in action on [ideone](https://ideone.com/Oefocm)

Comment: *since it is completely legal*: well gcc does also have warnings for valid but dangerous constructs so I would say it does not have it *yet* :)(AFAIK). Some other compilers may have such warning options. Note that PC-lint has an informational message (784) for this: *Nul character truncated from string*.

Comment: Thanks. The `_Static_assert()` could be a reasonable approach. It would make usage of the struct a little more cumbersome for developers.